# VisualStudio Code: TypeScript using ES6 module loading

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, es6-module-loader

I've been using TypeScript with AMD module loading(require.js) to develop a mobile app with Ionic.
VisualStudio Code also supports other types of module loading as ES6, which caught my attention for beeing the next standard syntax and more human readable(at least for me).
Unfortunately I can't find any example around of what I need to make it work with VisualStudio Code.
With AMD I need to have require.js bundled in my js's folder somewhere, configure it etc, etc. What I need for ES6? Or do I need anything at all, VSC takes care and add module loading library automatically?

Comment: VSC is just an editor. What you need is a build tool like WebPack or JSPM

Answer (score 0):

If you want good ES2015 support in VSC you should create a `jsconfig.json`. Here is a link to the official documentation:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Because no browser as implemented ES2015 modules yet, you have to use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/). You might also need [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Yeah, I got the `jsconfig.json` file set up already.
Ok, so webpack or rollup get into the middle like requirejs does for when using AMD? But as I could see, it prepares everything before going live, not like require.js that actively does it's things live in the browser, right?

Comment: Yes, but because not every browser fully supports ES2016 as of know the code is also transpile down to ES5. This is not directly done by webpack/rollup, but rather a plugin (for example babel).